# Javascript Regular Expression to validate date

Tags: javascript, regex, date

I am rather unfamiliar with regular expressions.  I am trying to write a regular expression for mm.dd.yyyy, mm/dd/yyyy or mm-dd-yyyy.  This is what I have so far, I am completely unsure if I am even close.

```
^[0-9]{4}-(((0[13578]|(10|12))-(0[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[0-1]))|(02-(0[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]))|((0[469]|11)-(0[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|30)))$
```

Thanks

Comment: @kennebec has supplied you with a perfect solution much better than a Regex, you should accept his answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
/^\d{2}[.\/-]\d{2}[.\/-]\d{4}$/
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/RbvfH/).

Note that this will allow them to be mixed up, i.e. `01/02-2010` would be valid. To stop this, write it out three times like so...

```
/^(?:\d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{4}|\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4}|\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4})$/
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/r9kgM/).

(or just check [cwolves's wonderful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5774931/javascript-regular-expression-to-validate-date/5775015#5775015).)

---

Your question title says...

> Javascript Regular Expression to validate date

If you also need to extract the portions, wrap them with parenthesis (`()`) which will turn them into capturing groups. They will be stored in members of the returned array if a successful match.

Comment: @ alex: where exactly do I put that? Thanks!

Comment: @willis You can use it like so `dateStr.match(/regex-here/)`. If it returns `null`, it didn't match.

Comment: `/^\d{2}([.\/-])\d{2}\1\d{4}$/`

no need for the 2nd example.

Answer (score 2):

```
/^\d{2}([.\/-])\d{2}\1\d{4}$/
```

will match `01/01/2000`, `01.01.2000`, NOT `01/01.2000`

```
/^(\d{2})([.\/-])(\d{2})\2(\d{4})$/
```

does the same while wrapping the three date parts.

Comment: So `\1` references the first group? I want to understand, thank you

Comment: This will also validate true for 98/42/2343, which is not a real date

Answer (score 2):

I have seen some monster regular expressions to match actual dates- they would not match 04/31/yyyy, for instance, or 02-29-2011.

It is simpler to try to make a date from the input, and then check the input.

```
function isvalid_mdy(s){
    var day, A= s.split(/\D+/).map(function(itm){
        return parseInt(itm, 10)
    });
    try{
        day= new Date(A[2], A[0]-1, A[1]);
        if(day.getMonth()+1== A[0] && day.getDate()== A[1]) return day;
        throw 'Bad Date Format';
    }
    catch(er){
        return NaN;
    }

}

var s1= '04/31/2011';
isvalid_mdy(s1)

/*  returned value: (Number)
NaN
```

*/

Comment: This is the best I've seen so far. Well built.

Answer (score 0):

In PHP I use named matches, so different formats are easy:

```
$format = 'y-m-d'; // or 'd-m-y' or 'd/m/y' etc
$regexp = '#^'.strtr(preg_quote($format), array('y' => '(?P<year>(?:1|2)\d{3})', 'm' => '(?P<month>\d\d?)', 'd' => '(?P<day>\d\d?)')).'$#';
```

but I don't think it's possible like that in JS. Maybe named matches some other way...

**edit**
I tried this:

```
'2004-8-29'.match(/^(\3\d{4})-(\2\d\d?)-(\1\d\d?)$/)
```

but I don't think that's it... (Notice the \3, \2 and \1 before the actual captures/matches)

In order 1, 2, 3, it matches. In order 3, 2, 1, it doesn't. Not sure what the `\1`, `\2` and `\3` do =)

Answer (score 0):

I don't like repeating the patterns once each for `.`, `-` and `/`

Try something like the below:

```
^(\d{2})(\/|-|\.)(\d{2})\2(\d{4})$
```

Note the use of `\2` representing the second matching group which is the group of `.`, `-` or `/`. This will make sure that whatever symbol was between mm and dd will be matched between dd and yyyy.

Answer (score 0):

An interesting trick is that you can use Date.parse() to do something along those lines:

```
// 1303617600000
Date.parse('4/24/2011')

// 1303617600000
Date.parse('4-24-2011')

// 1303617600000
Date.parse('4.24.2011')

// NaN
Date.parse('4/32/2011')

// NaN
Date.parse('foo')
```

It's not perfectly strict.  For example, it will successfully parse 2/30/2011 as valid.  It's a good 99%-strict sanity test though.

Comment: @Dave Ward: I'm not trying to milk your answer, but could you write it out in full, I'm not understanding it as is? thanks

Comment: Are you sure this works? `var d = Date.parse("4-24-2011");` gives `NaN`

Comment: @manojlds: Yes, I tested all of those on the console before posting.  It might not work if your browser's locale isn't one that uses mm/dd/yyyy dates though.

Comment: It works for '/' but not for '.' and '-' for me, irrespective of mm/dd/yyyy or dd/mm/yyyy. Anyway, if this won't work based on user's locale etc. then the solution is faulty.

Comment: @willis0924: Test for `Date.parse(dateString) !== NaN`.

Comment: @manojlds: Interesting; it looks like only Chrome parses `.` and `-`, but Firefox and IE don't.  Easy enough to .replace() those to `/` though.

Comment: `Date.parse('4/32/2011')` returns a number..not NaN. (tried with FF and IE9)

Comment: @vsync: That does return `NaN` in Chrome.

Comment: I wish this worked and could be used in real-life cases, but as it is now, it is entirely useless as no one develops entirely for Chrome..