# Accessing a specific item in an object array(javascript)

Tags: javascript

Any one with an idea on how i can access the "13-02-2018"?
Help will be highly appreciated.
[the object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tJXVi.png)
I have named the array "Data"

```
for (var i = 0; i < Data.length;i++){
                var temp =Data[i].[0];
                    }
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Any more information on the scope of the work?

Comment: You'd have to search the array for that value

Comment: Do you have to dynamically access the property? ... Also do you have control of what the property is called? If possible you should consider changing the structure of your object.

Comment: @ABear i have updated the question

Comment: I am receiving the data from an API, the dates vary. I was wondering if i can extract that value(which is the date) and store it in a variable @Tyler

Comment: Seeing as the property name is a date, I expect it to change. Which makes the situation quite complex to do in a very clean and simple way. As far as I know, JL's answer might be the best direction to go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is "how do I list the keys in an object?"

```
var foo = { bar: 'baz' };
for (var key in foo) { console.log(key); }
// outputs 'bar'
```

More information about keys: [Checking if a key exists in a JavaScript object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1098040/checking-if-a-key-exists-in-a-javascript-object?rq=1)

EDIT: OP updated his question and data.

```
var foo = [ { bar: 'baz' }, { buz: 'biz' } ];
for (var i = 0; i < foo.length; i++) {
    for (var key in foo[i]) {
        console.log(key);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your question should include a full description of your data that's neatly formatted.

Answer (score 1):

My solution would be to loop through the data, as you are doing, and check to see if the element is of a date format. I assume the dates are always of the same format (ie "dd-mm-yyyy)? If so I would check they match that format using regex (there are other ways to do this but I love regex!), so try looking at a thread like this: [date format detection by regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18758772/how-do-i-validate-a-date-in-this-format-yyyy-mm-dd-using-jquery) - all credit to the original answers in the link. Beware you will need to update the accepted answer so you get "dd-mm-yyyy" (I'm not certain if the below will work out the box as I don't know how Date() works in JS, you may have to rearrange it to a "yyyy-mm-dd" format before using it).

But yeah I'd go for something like:

```
for (var i = 0; i<data.length; i++){
   for (var item in data[i]) {
       if(item.isValidDate()) {
           \\do your stuff, for example:
           var temp = item;
       }
   }
}

function isValidDate(dateString) {
   var regEx = /^\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4}$/;
   if(!dateString.match(regEx)) return false;  // Invalid format
      var d = new Date(dateString);
   if(!d.getTime() && d.getTime() !== 0) return false; // Invalid date
      return d.toISOString().slice(0,10) === dateString;
}
```

Even if this doesn't work, hopefully it gives you an idea of a possible path you could go down :)