# Check whether given string is date value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I need to check whether given string is date or not.
Note: Without using any library

I try to use this

```
if (!isNaN(str) || isNaN(Date.parse(str))) {
    console.log("Not a Date");
} else {
    console.log('It is Date');
}
```

It works in all scenarios **except one**, if the given input is `Hello 2`, it returns `It is Date`

So, is there any way with which I can appropriately validate my string against Date?

Comment: If you know what date format you want to get, you could work with regular expressions.

Something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18758772/how-do-i-validate-a-date-in-this-format-yyyy-mm-dd-using-jquery/18759013

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like your requirement is to validate the date which has year between 1000 - 9999, with validate day and month mapping.

Here is what you should be doing

- store a variable by converting it to Date `const myDate = new Date(your_date_string);`
- Then you should write logic to check if the time returned by date is valid number `isNaN(myDate.getTime())`
- Then you should write logic to check if the year is within the range (you require) For eg: `myDate.getFullYear() > 9999 || myDate.getFullYear() < 1000`
- Then you should check if the day and month processed is valid. For that you can get month and date by using `myDate.getUTCMonth()` & `myDate.getUTCDate()` accordingly. and check the mapping. Please note UTCMonth and UTCDate is index.
- if all the above is valid then the date is valid else not.
  Somewhat like  this

```
function isValidDate(myDate) {
  const d = new Date(myDate);
  if (Object.prototype.toString.call(d) === '[object Date]') {
    if (isNaN(d.getTime()) || d.getFullYear() > 9999 || d.getFullYear() < 1000 || !(your_date_mapping_logic)) {
      console.log('Invalid Date.');
    } else {
      console.log('Valid Date.');
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with the below condition

```js
if (isFinite(new Date(str).getTime())) {
    console.log("Not a Date");
} else {
    console.log('It is Date');
}
```

Comment: It works if i give input "Hello 2" but if the string is number like "213213" it says that "It is Date"

Comment: Yes, the string is successfully getting parsed to date `Tue Jan 01 213213`

Comment: Are you looking for any specific date format validation?

Comment: No, the given string could be in any date format, it should validate as Date otherwise not