# Jquery validation method for date in dd/mm/yyyy format

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, jquery-validate

I want to add new validation method to jquery validation that validates date in **dd/mm/yyyy** format ex(28/01/2015)

I tried :

```
$.validator.addMethod("dateFormat",function(value, element) {
    return value.match(/^(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[\/\-](0?[1-9]|1[012]) [\/\-]\d{4}$/);
 });
```

which is not working as expected.. any better way of doing it?

Comment: **What exactly does *"not working as expected"* mean?**  No validation?  Validation is incorrect? Console errors?

Answer (score -1):

I'm sorry I can't provide a more personal answer, but there's already a lot on this. Does this link help?

[Javascript - Regex to validate date format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7388001/javascript-regex-to-validate-date)

Example from linked answer:

```
var dateReg = /^\d{2}([./-])\d{2}\1\d{4}$/

"22-03-1981".match(dateReg) // matches
"22.03-1981".match(dateReg) // does not match
"22.03.1981".match(dateReg) // matches
```

Another link that might help:

[Javascript date regex DD/MM/YYYY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5465375/javascript-date-regex-dd-mm-yyyy)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Updated with a valid example from one of the links.