# DateFormat that validate the value both in 2 digit and 4 digit?

Tags: javascript, jquery, date

I am using custom datepicker. In that, i am following standard date format structures. in this user can provide the last two digit of the year else 4 digits. So, I need to validate this two different formats and then process. How to proceed this? Is there any other format available which accept the year as both 2 digits or 4 digits format.
For example if i am giving date to "11/09/1999" its should convert to 11/09/99 properly on focus out

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript - Regex to validate date format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7388001/javascript-regex-to-validate-date-format)

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you try the input type 'Date' instead of using a custom datepicker. The input date tags will be helpful to handle data easily.

```
<input type="date" id="myDate" value="2014-02-09">
```

Comment: No i am in situation to use custom datepicker. Also in that if i give 09/19/1999 its should convert to 09/19/99

Comment: Share the code that you use to get date with the custom date picker. Just wanted to know how the custom datepicker is used.