# Check date with regular expression

Tags: javascript, regex

How to use this regular expression to validate the date in this case?

```
var regex = new RegExp(/[\d-: ]/, 'g');
console.log(regex.test(updated_post_datetime));
```

The input will be something like that **2011-03-29 12:22somestring**
It has to return false in that case, but it returns true.

Comment: What do you expect `2011-02-29 25:61:73` to return, out of curiosity?

Comment: false, but I don't know how to write it properly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you e.g. add `^`, `+` and `$` it will work, where

```
"^"  =  from the beginning of the line
"+"  =  one or more of chosen character
"$"  =  to end of line
```

```js
var regex = /^[\d-: ]+$/;
console.log(regex.test("2011-03-29 12:22somestring"));
console.log(regex.test("2011-03-29 12:22"));
console.log(regex.test("2011-03-30 12:22"));
console.log(regex.test("2011-04-01 12:22"));
console.log(regex.test("2011-05-19 12:22"));
```

---

Do note though, this will return true for e.g. `123` as well, so if you intend to validate that it is really a date, you need something like one of these:

- [Javascript - Regex to validate date format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7388001/javascript-regex-to-validate-date-format)
- [Javascript date regex DD/MM/YYYY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5465375/javascript-date-regex-dd-mm-yyyy)

Comment: Thanks. That was what I search for.

Comment: Very nice answer!

Answer (score 0):

An alternative approach:

```
console.log(!isNaN(Date.parse(updated_post_datetime)));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
var regex = new RegExp(/^(?:[12]\d{3})-(?:(0[1-9])|(1[0-2]))-(?:([0-2][1-9])|(3[0-1]))\s+(([01][1-9])|(2[0-3])):([0-5][0-9])|(2[0-3])/, 'g');
console.log(regex.test(updated_post_datetime));
```

or better try to create a new date for it

```
var test1 = '2011-03-29 12:22';
console.log(test1 + ' test is: ' + isDate(test1));

var test2 = '2011-02-29 25:61:73';
console.log(test2 + ' test is: ' + isDate(test2));

function isDate(value) {
    if (!value) return false;

    try {
        var dt = new Date(value);
        return dt instanceof Date && !isNaN(dt.valueOf())
    }
    catch (e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

because validating date with regular expression alone is not enough